# CC.Net + VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am new to CC.Net. I want to integrate my VS 2008 project with CC.Net. I am using VSS. 
Is MSBuild or NAnt necessary to integration?

Can anybody tell me the simple steps to integrate CC.Net with VSS to build my visual studio 2008 project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Neither MSBuild nor Nant is necessary - both are optional helpers.

You can get ccnet to build your VS 2008 project/solution directly if you have visual studio installed on the build machine.

Use either the VisualStudio or Executable task see:[Tasks](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Task+Blocks)

If your code is purely managed you can use msbuild to avoid the need to install visual studio on your build machine.

You'll also need a source control block and a publishing block - in general the documentation on [ccnet](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configuring+the+Server) is pretty good.

Comment: We found the MSBuild Task was more stable than the VisualStudio Tasks